# Java authenticate user within a different domain.

Tags: java

I'm building a single signon app and I'm wondering if it's possible to authenticate a user within a completely different website without using oauth, "not a possible solution". I'm currently able to do this by copying the other websites login form into my page along with the post url, hidden field, username/password field. I would much rather do this behind the scenes if possible where credentials wouldn't be exposed. I'm wondering if something like httpclient would be able to accomplish this task.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is theoretically possible.  You are trying to use the other web site as an authentication provider.  You need to find out what authentication services the other website offers - you could try federated authentication, LDAP-based authn, kerberos, etc., but if the site you want to authenticate to doesn't support any of these, then you aren't going use any of these protocols.